# OpenCV Mat obejct is not filled from VideoCapture properly if imshow() is NOT used

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, v4l2

I'm trying to capture sequence of frames from a webcam and show it as QImage:

```
cv::Mat mat;
cap >> mat; //cap is cv::VideoCapture("/dev/video0")
cv::Mat dest;
cv::cvtColor(mat, dest, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
QImage img((uchar*) dest.data, dest.cols, dest.rows, dest.step, 
    QImage::Format_RGB888);
ui->vid->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

It worked with default settings but I needed to switch from GStreamer to V4L2* so now I open the webcam like this:

```
//cap is cv::VideoCapture("/dev/video0", cv::CAP_V4L2)
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, 
    cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')); //returns true
```

Now I end up with white image with some artifacts BUT if I add `cv::imshow("frame", mat)` right after the line with `>>`, I can see the captured frame with no problem like the `mat` object was filled... but I end up with this extra window from `opencv2/highgui.hpp` I don't need or want, it shows the same thing I can see in my QLabel. What `cv::imshow` does except actually displaying the image? I think I need to do it manually...

- - GStreamer just stopped to work all of sudden, and I was getting this error:

> [ WARN:0] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp
> (933) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position:
> status=0, value=-1, duration=-1

I'm reading it's a bug so I wanted to switch to V4L2.

Comment: are you running that code in a loop or sth.? does dest leave the scope while Qt is trying to display it? Is it possible to perform a deep copy of `img` during `ui->vid->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));`? Imshow shouldnt do anything, but if you have a waitKey somewhere, it is only doing something if an opencv window is available (so waitKey with or without imshow can lead to a different timing in your program)..

Comment: @Micka thank you. Your comment made me investigate further, I didn't know QImage won't just copy whatever it needs! It's smarter than that.

Comment: yes, in imaging, copies are omitted often because they are quite expensive and can destroy applications which have to process very high fps for example.